# error: no matching package named `sc-consensus-grandpa` found

Tags: pallet, evm, ethereum

I want to add pallet ethereum in our runtime but after adding this line:

`pallet-ethereum = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/frontier", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.39" }`

I'm facing this `` error: no matching package named `sc-consensus-grandpa` found ``

Comment: Which branch version you are using in other pallets ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you mentioned typically occurs when a package or module is not found in the specified package repository or in your local environment.
you may try  to change `sc-consensus-grandpa` with `sc-finality-grandpa` make sure you use same branch of `substrate` and `Frontier`  if you are using `polkadot-v0.9.39` of frontier then switch to `polkadot-v0.9.39` in substrate also.